# plt.ylim not giving me the ranges i want

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

My code is as follow:

```
plt.figure(figsize =(15,4) )
sns.set_style("white")
plt.ylim(500,30000)
ax = sns.lineplot(data = df,x = 'date', y = 'number of requests', hue = 'account_name',style="account_name",markers=True, dashes=False)
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=[0.94, -0.3], frameon='false', ncol=6)
plt.title('Number of requests over the time', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Requests', fontsize=15)
plt.grid(True, linestyle = ':')
sns.despine()
```

but the y ranges are: 5000,10000,15000,20000,25000,30000.
My problem that i have requests starting in very low amount and some are very high as in the screenshot - how can i control the ranges? this graph is not so readable :([image]

Comment: `ylim` changes the limits, not the scale. Sounds like you need to change the scale. Depending on the data, a log scale might be appropriate.

Comment: how should i do it?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is `ax.set_ylim(-5000, 25000)`. As @GigBen commented, the other way to adjust the y-axis tick is to change to log format or create your own.

simple:

```
ax.set_ylim([-5000,25000])
```

[image]

log style:

```
ax.yscale('log')
```

[image]

yticks customize:

```
ax.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks()[::2])
```

[image]

full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,4))
sns.set_style("white")

ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, x='date', y='number of requests', hue="account_name", style="account_name", markers=True, dashes=False)
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=[0.94, -0.3], frameon='false', ncol=6)
ax.set_title('Number of requests over the time', fontsize=20)
ax.set_xlabel('Date', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Requests', fontsize=15)
ax.grid(True, linestyle = ':')
# update
ax.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks()[::2])

plt.show()
```

Comment: not solving it.  how can i get scale with more ranges? for example jump of 2500 until 25000.

Comment: Doesn't every example solve the purpose? Which of the following is a challenge?